# Left shift tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, torch

I have a tensor `a` of shape `(1, N, 1)`. I need to left shift the tensor along dimension `1` and add a new value as replacement. I have found a way to make this work and following is the code.

```
a = torch.from_numpy(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
a = a.unsqueeze(0).unsqeeze(2)  # (1, 3, 1), my data resembles this shape, therefore the two unsqueeze
# want to left shift a along dim 1 and insert a new value at the end
# I achieve the required shifts using the following code
b = a.squeeze
c = b.roll(shifts=-1)
c[-1] = 4
c = c.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(2)
# c = [[[2], [3], [4]]]
```

My question is, is there a simpler way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to squeeze and perform your operations followed by unsqeezing your input tensor `a`. Instead you can directly do those two operations as follows:

```
# No need to squeeze
c = torch.roll(a, shifts=-1, dims=1)
c[:,-1,:] = 4
# No need to unsqeeze
# c = [[[2], [3], [4]]]
```

Comment: There is no torch method that combines these operations right?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, No.